# How to check whether the server was up for more than 15 minutes?

Tags: java, string, timestamp

I have a String which contains total time the server was up -

```
String uptime = data.get("machine_uptime");
```

As an example, uptime variable will have values like this - `183:23:15.195804` or `00:01:17.302305`. I need to check whether my machine was up more than 15 minutes. So I came up with the below code

```
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(uptime.split(":")[1]);

if (minutes > 15) {
    flag = true;
}
```

Is this the right way to  do this check?

Comment: Your code would say that `100:00:12.345678` is less than 15 minutes.

Comment: @immibis Oops I missed that so it is definitely wrong.

Comment: @immibis `Integer.parseInt` does not parse octal numbers.  It would return 9 just like the questioner thinks it would.

Comment: Your approach is fine except that you need to check hours too.  Also, I think 15.5 minutes of more than 15, but your `minutes > 15` check wouldn't catch this; I'd change it to `>=`, but it depends on your needs.  Please ignore the comment about octal; it's wrong.

Comment: @ajb You're right, I was thinking of C's `atoi` and relatives.

Comment: @immibis `Integer.decode` does the kind of thing you were thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
flag = uptime.matches("[^:]*[1-9][^:]*:.*|[^:]+:(1[5-9]|[2-5]\\d).*");
```

This asserts 15 by:

- any non-zero hours value, *or*
- any hours value with minutes:

  - starting with "1" then "5-9" - ie 15 to 19 minutes
  - starting with a number greater than "1" - ie 20 to 59 minutes

Comment: Can you explain what does it do? And how does it check for 15 minutes window?

Comment: @immi yes, but does now

Comment: Why [5-8] and not [5-9]?

Comment: @immi cos I'm thumbing on an iPhone and drunk after a Xmas break up party :)